# Please help me improve my babel answer?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, specific-question

I have authored an answer to a [SWR](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/462217/87426). While I believe my suggestion provides a near precise answer to the asked question, it seems to be rather unliked.

I understand the word may be rare, but an unusual word usually does not generate a lot of controversy.

If I could get some help understanding how the answer should be improved, or why the answer is considered such a bad one, that feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a **HOT META POST**. Congratulations on making the Big Time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer has eight up-votes and four down-votes, so it's more *controversial* than *bad*. I suspect the controversy stems from your discussion of "babble", since some commenters disagree that it's not the same as "babel" in this context.

You could try adding a definition of "babble" to support your position, or (if those definitions don't pan out), you could soften your statement to list "babble" as a similar (etymologically unrelated), but potentially more ambiguous, term.

---

Incidentally, I would tend to agree that ["babble"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/babble) is an OK term here; the relevant ODO definition is

> 1. *[i mass noun]* The sound of people talking simultaneously.

But I also agree with you that there is a greater connotation of rapidity, as seen in the first definition of the verb:

> 1. Talk rapidly and continuously in a foolish, excited, or incomprehensible way.

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify the connotation comes from the verb definition, and soften my stance.

Answer (score 2):

Provide some historical references to accentuate the legitimacy of the usage.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel

Comment: Thanks, I have added some context.